# Unable to import GPG key of node

Tags: apt, gnupg

**I'm working on a very old ubuntu 8**

I'm trying to do this

```
$ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Same problem using `sudo`:

```
$ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | sudo apt-key -add 
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Found the problem, but not the solution:

```
curl -k https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

curl infos:

```
curl --version
curl 7.18.0 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.1
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: Unsupported? curl or apt-key add?

Comment: The entire OS version is unsupported. Anyway, you'll need to build a newer version of OpenSSL from source, then build a version of curl using that, and then try this.

Comment: I know but my (job-)client has this old version. sadly... Thanks for the idea to build from source. It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built an updated version of curl

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Install any build dependencies needed for curl
sudo apt-get build-dep curl

# Downloaded and build lastest available version at 02/08/2017
mkdir ~/curl
cd ~/curl
wget --no-check-certificate http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.52.1.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf curl-7.52.1.tar.bz2
cd curl-7.52.1

# The usual steps for building an app from source
./configure
make
sudo make install

# Resolve any issues of C-level lib
# location caches ("shared library cache")
sudo ldconfig
```

After that, I successfully downloaded and added the node key